# Android ViewHolder is not properly recycled and keeps bitmaps on the heap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

A couple of things are happening here:

1. I tried using Coil / Glide, both suffer the same problem
   -> I suspect the problem is not in the image loading itself, rather in the recycling process of the view holder
2. LeakCanary is not reporting any memory leaks
3. I used an Lru Cache to store Contact Photos by their lookup keys
   -> Cached Image is loaded by Coil / Glide, but still assigned on the heap (the same image is now present twice on the heap)

**This is how it looks:**

[image]
As you can see, I have over 1000 bitmap allocations that are taking a whopping 123MB on the heap even if my list only contains around 80 items and should only display about 10 of them at once.

**Here you can see how it quickly fills the heap after scrolling from top to bottom a couple times:**

[image]

**This is how my adapter looks:**

```kotlin
class CustomerAdapter(
    private val viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    private val listener: CustomerClickListener,
    private val context: Context,
    private val prefsShared: PrefsShared,
    private val imageManager: ImageManager,
) : ListAdapter<Customer..., RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        CustomerViewHolderPhoto(
            context, <-------------|
            viewLifecycleOwner, <--|--- Are these actually the problem?
            listener, <------------|
            imageManager,
            binding
        )
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class CustomerViewHolderPhoto(
    private val context: Context,
    private val viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    private val listener: CustomerAdapter.CustomerClickListener,
    private val imageManager: ImageManager,
    private val binding: ViewHolderCustomerItemPhotoBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), Releasable {

    fun bind(contact: EntityContactWithCustomerWithPhoneNumbersAndVisits) {
        ...
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onCustomerClicked(contact)
        }

        imageManager.loadContactImageIntoImageViewAsync(
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner,
            imageView = binding.imageViewCustomer,
            lookupKey = contact.contact.contactBookLookupKey,
        )
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class CustomerFragment : Fragment(), CustomerAdapter.CustomerClickListener {
    ...

    private fun setupCustomerAdapter(): CustomerAdapter {
        val viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val viewAdapter = CustomerAdapter(
            viewLifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner,
            listener = this,
            context = requireContext(),
            prefsShared = prefsShared,
            imageManager = imageManager
        )

        binding.recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
        }

        return viewAdapter
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any memory leaks I would start there?  If not then I guess`ImageManager` is lasting longer than the `Fragment` lifecycle and using some sort of lru caching and retaining a reference to the `Bitmap`

Comment: The memory leaks have been there before I added the Lru cache, the imageManager is a singleton which is encapsulates loading of contact images.

Comment: How do you know these are memory leaks and just not valid references just held in memory?  Memory leaks only occur when there is no way to clear a lower scoped object from a higher scoped object.  What happens when you exit the app and restart without the process dying - do you still have duplicated references, or just the ones in lru cache in the singleton? Glide has options like : `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)`
  `skipMemoryCache(true)` to skip caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image clearing can be done in onViewRecycled, f.e. Glide.with(context).clear(imageView).
Plus in the case of Glide, it will be useful to check caching strategies and choose what you need.
And as size optimization, when a loaded image can be smaller then the ImageView will be usefull to use Glide.with(context).load(image).centerInside()...

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I am now only having 60 allocations on the heap. Much better.

Comment: How Glide internally works in optimising the bitmaps?